# Facebook Users Search API

Tags: php, facebook

I am using latest version of facebook php sdk i want searched user list.

```
$response = $fb->get('search?q=programming&type=user', '{access-token}');
```

$response is always returns blank value in version 5.

Thanks in advance..!!!

Comment: Should `serach` be `search`?

Comment: Yes it is typo and corrected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was removed in 4/2018 already.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes#search-4-4

> You can no longer use the /search endpoint with the following object types:
>
> - event
> - group
> - page
> - user